# What do I need to study to do this Gaussian question?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm taking a probabilistic machine learning course and need to understand some background mathematics, including the following question:

Let $x$ be a Gaussian random variable with mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2$. What is the expected value of $2x^2$? Show what form the distribution of $2(x − μ)^2$ takes.

I'd really appreciate an explanation of how to answer this and what areas I should study to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variable transformation. Have a look at Allan Gut's An Intermediate Course in Probability (it's available for free online if you have access to Springer). Essentially, if $X=Y^2$, for example, where you know the distribution of $X$, you can use the cumulative distribution and do an inverse transformation.

Answer (score 0):

$2(X-\mu)^2$ is twice the squared error, so has a scaled [chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with one degree of freedom.  Its mean is $E[2(X-\mu)^2]=2 \sigma^2$, which indicates the scaling factor.

Since $2X^2 = 2(X-\mu)^2 + 4X\mu - 2\mu^2$, you can derive that its mean is $E[2X^2] = 2 \sigma^2 +2 \mu^2.$  Its distribution (which you are not asked for) is a scaled [non-central chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) again with one degree of freedom.

You need to study statistical distributions, plus Wikipedia's particular presentation of such things, which in my view is good but not always complete: for example, if you follow the links I give above, you need to taking into account [location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_parameter) and [scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter).

The Coursera course [Mathematical Biostatistics Boot Camp 1](https://www.coursera.org/course/biostats) from Brian Caffo at Johns Hopkins deals with this kind of topic: I think a current edition is about to end soon, so you could do it quickly (possibly without the certificate).